# React Filter array of objects by date within a certain range using buttons, moment js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, filter, momentjs

So i have an array objects with dates and scores. I would like to create an onclick handler that updates data everytime i click one of the 4 buttons. My 4 buttons represent 3 months, 6 months,  12 months and reset.  I would like to filter this data from todays date to "blank" months ago. I am thinking of using moment and here is what i have so far. Just not sure if im going the right direction or how to solve this issue.

```
const threeMonths = moment().startOf('day').subtract(3, 'month').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
const sixMonths = moment().startOf('day').subtract(6, 'month').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
const twelveMonths = moment().startOf('day').subtract(12, 'month').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Example: Clicking the 3 months button
I would like to filter this data from todays date to 3 months ago

Starting:

```
 Data = [ 
    {date: '2023-01-22', score: 57.675},
    {date: '2022-11-05', score: 60.675},
    {date: '2022-12-11', score: 78.675},
    {date: '2022-08-26', score: 81.675}
    ]

<Button onclick= {} > 3 months </Button>
```

After 3 month button click: Only dates within 3 months remain

```
Data = [ 
    {date: '2023-01-22', score: 57.675},
    {date: '2022-11-05', score: 60.675},
    {date: '2022-12-11', score: 78.675},
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-zhukovsky-ekroop?file=/src/App.js)

store your data in state and on click of button use javascript filter method to filter the array and update state.

Comment: My data is coming from a useeffect, so its already stored in a state. Would you mind showing example code of what you recommended?

Comment: @makiwumi Added a code sandbox link, I hope this might be helpful